# How to send notifications or messages to user?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs in the current user space, but in the background, permanently minimized.

It needs to send notifications, via the system tray, or Windows.UI.Notifications mechanism (or something else of this flavor).

How is this done in powershell on Win11/Win10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [BurntToast](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast) module is what you're looking for:

> PowerShell Module for displaying Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 Toast Notifications

Here's a simple example taken from the readme:

```
New-BurntToastNotification `
    -AppLogo C:\smile.jpg `
    -Text "Don't forget to smile!",
     'Your script ran successfully, celebrate!'
```

Result:

[image: Toast]

Answer (score 3):

```
# this can be a manual input array of users as well
$users = ((Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username).Split('\')[1]
$WhatToSend = Read-Host "What do you want the message to be"
foreach ($user in $users){
    & msg $user $WhatToSend
}
```

```
#if you want to send the message to all users then use a wildcard
msg * $WhatToSend
```

Comment: Thanks!  That does work. But it pops a modal messagebox. How to make it one of those bubbles from the system tray that are informative but non intrusive?  (You can post a second answer, fwiw)

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica, small correction: the message box is _always on top_, but it isn't _modal_. Also, for the sake of completeness (it is still no substitute for [toast notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts)): You can make the message box auto-close after a given number of seconds with `/TIME:$secs`

Comment: `msg.exe` only accepts messages up to 255 characters which is a no-go for my use case, I went with `Wscript.Shell.Popup` instead